# Computing $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm computing different minimal polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_3$. I found that I can look at elements of the form $\sqrt[4]{2}$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[\sqrt{2}]$ and  in particular I found the four fourth roots of two in that field are $1+2\sqrt{2},1-2\sqrt{2},2+\sqrt{2},2-\sqrt{2}$ while the square roots of 2 are $\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}$.

Now I'm trying to calculate the minimal polinomial of $\alpha = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt[4]{2}$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$ and I obtain that any $\alpha$  must be a root of $$(X-1)^2(X^2+2X+2)$$ (see the edit below to understand how I obtain it) This gives me at most 3 possible $\alpha$. However, if I sum the elements above I get six different values.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= \sqrt{2}+\sqrt[4]{2}\\
(\alpha - \sqrt{2})^2 &= \sqrt{2}\\(\alpha^2+2)^2 &= ((2 \alpha + 1)\sqrt{2})^2\\\alpha^4 - 4 \alpha^2 - 8 \alpha + 2 &=0\\\alpha^4 - \alpha^2 + \alpha+2 &=0\\(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha^2+2\alpha^2+2)&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that $\pm 2\sqrt{2}=\mp \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews still i get six possible summands which can not be all roots of the polynomial i calculate

Comment: When you compute $\sqrt2+\sqrt[4]2$ I presume you want the roots to be compatible, i.e., the $\sqrt2$ is the square of the $\sqrt[4]2$. You then get three possible values $\alpha=1$ or $\alpha=-1\pm\sqrt2$. I suppose you could choose your $\sqrt2$ to be $-(\sqrt[4]2)^2$, but that would be perverse surely?

Comment: You don't tell us how you "obtain" that polynomial.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I specify my calculations in the edit. it appears to me that i'm assuming $\sqrt{2}=(\sqrt[4]{2})^2$ as LordSharktheUnknown suggests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me suggest an approach that might be precisely orthogonal to your strategy. We’re tourists in the land of characteristic three, in which $2=-1$, so your first adjunction is of $i=\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt2$. So you’ve adjoined a primitive fourth root of unity, which lies in the field $\Bbb F_9$, the (unique) quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_3$.

But the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_9$ is of order eight, so that you have the eighth roots of unity free of charge by adjoining $i$. The nonzero elements of $\Bbb F_9$ that aren’t in the set $\{\pm1,\pm i\}$ are $\pm1\pm i$, four in number, and there is your total list of the four possibilities for what you called $\sqrt[4]2$. Just take one of them, $1+i$, whose $\Bbb F_3$-conjugate is $1-i$. Their common minimal polynomial is clearly $X^2-X-1$. The other two are $-1\pm i$, and their common polynomial is $X^2+X-1$.

I think that with this explicit description of the elements of $\Bbb F_9$, you can answer your question. Note that one of the one of the elements “$\sqrt2+\sqrt[4]2$” is in fact equal to $1$.

Comment: In the spirit of @Lubin's answer, see math.stackexchange.com/a/2458854/300700. In the notations therein, $\omega$ is a primitive $8$-th root of $1$, and one choice for your ( $\sqrt [4] 2 , \sqrt 2$) could be ($\omega, \omega^2$) ; if $\omega$ is chosen to be a root of $X^2 + X -1$, then $\omega +\omega^2 =1$. Similar calculations for the other choices.